# Envío de archivos adjuntos en un correo con SES

Tags: vb.net

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy utilizando la API de Amazon para el envío de correos, este es SES, ya el correo me envía bien, pero al momento de adjuntar un pdf me genera problema, ya que cuando llega el correo, intento abrir el pdf y dice que este está dañado. Estoy utilizando vb.net

Este es mi codigo

```
Dim archivo = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~\ruta"), "prueba.pdf")

Dim stream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("To: kgjdj@gmail" &
                                                          vbLf & "From: prueba@gmail" &
                                                          vbLf & "Subject: Prueba" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;" &
                                                          vbLf & "        boundary=YWVhZDFlY2QzMGQ2N2U0YTZmODU" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "--YWVhZDFlY2QzMGQ2N2U0YTZmODU" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "--YWVhZDFlY2QzMGQ2N2U0YTZmODU" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & cuerpo &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "--YWVhZDFlY2QzMGQ2N2U0YTZmODU" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Type: application/pdf;" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Prueba.pdf" &
                                                          vbLf & "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & archivo &
                                                          vbLf & "" &
                                                          vbLf & "--YWVhZDFlY2QzMGQ2N2U0YTZmODU--"))


        Dim senderAddress = "prueba@gmail"
        Dim receiverAddress = "kgjdj@gmail"

        Dim lista = New List(Of String) From {
                        receiverAddress
                    }

        Using client = New AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(RegionEndpoint.USEast1)
            Dim sendRequest = New SendRawEmailRequest With {
                .Source = senderAddress,
                .Destinations = lista,
            .RawMessage = New RawMessage With {
                .Data = Stream
                }
            }

            Try
                Console.WriteLine("Sending email using Amazon SES...")
                Dim response = client.SendRawEmail(sendRequest)
                Console.WriteLine("The email was sent successfully.")
            Catch ex As Exception
                Console.WriteLine("The email was not sent.")
                Console.WriteLine("Error message: " & ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
```

Comment: Estoy casi seguro que estás usando mal SES, lo que haces con el `stream` es lo que está matando al `PDF`. No conozco el cliente SES de Amazon, pero he trabajado bastante con correos en VB.NET y por experiencia y por lo que veo en tu código te sugiero que busques la documentación de SES.

Answer (score 0):

> Para adjuntar un archivo a un correo electrónico, debe codificar el
>   archivo adjunto con la codificación Base64. Los archivos adjuntos
>   normalmente se colocan en partes de mensaje MIME dedicadas, que
>   incluyen los siguientes encabezados:
>
> - **Content-Type:** el tipo de archivo del archivo adjunto. A continuación, se muestran ejemplos de declaraciones comunes de
>     Content-Type de MIME:
>
>   - **Archivo de texto sin formato:** `Content-Type: text/plain; name="sample.txt"`
>   - **Documento de Microsoft Word:** `Content-Type: application/msword; name="document.docx"`
>   - **Imagen JPG: Content-Type:** `image/jpeg; name="photo.jpeg"`
> - **Content-Disposition:** especifica cómo debe gestionar el contenido el cliente de correo electrónico del destinatario. Para los archivos
>     adjuntos, este valor es `Content-Disposition: attachment.`
> - **Content-Transfer-Encoding:** el esquema que se utilizó para codificar el archivo adjunto. Para los archivos adjuntos, este valor
>     casi siempre es base64.
>
> Amazon SES acepta los tipos de archivos más comunes.

<sub>*Fuente: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-raw.html#send-email-mime-encoding-files*</sub>